# Visual Studio Debug - Window start screen

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio 2010 to start a Windows Form Application (while debugging) on particular screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you could try this. Note that there is no error checking for what happens if no secondary screen is connected.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ScreenPositioning
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            #if DEBUG
            var screen = Screen.AllScreens;
            foreach (var s in screen)
            {
                if (!s.Primary)
                {
                    this.Bounds = s.Bounds;
                    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                }
            }
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I 'm making some assumptions here:

1. That by "while debugging" you mean "when the VS debugger is going to be attached to the process", not "when running a debug build"
2. That by "particular screen" you mean "particular piece of application UI", not "particular computer monitor" (I hadn't even considered that before I saw Mikael Östberg's answer)

**Answer:**

Not automatically. You will have to arrange for this with code, i.e. set up VS to launch your application with a specific parameter when debugging and then change the code to do something like this:

```
var mainForm = new FormToShowNormally();
#if DEBUG
if(debugParameterOnCommandLine) {
    mainForm = new FormToShowWhenDebugging();
}
#endif

Application.Run(mainForm);
```

Comment: When I think about it, I think he actually meant on a particular screen as in monitor. I actually don't know if my solution solves that.